# How to move selected items from one dropdown group list (optgroup)to another dropdown group list (optgroup) using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optgroup

I have two dropdown grouped lists (Optgroup). I would like to swap items between these two html controls using move right, move left buttons. I may select one or more items from the left side dropdown grouped list items then click on move right button. In this case I am able to move the selected items to right side dropdown grouped list. But items are not inserted as grouped list like left side dropdown grouped list.

Here is my html controls.

```
<select name="AvailableFields" id="AvailableFields" multiple="multiple" size="10">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<optgroup label="Group A">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group B">
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<button type="button" title="Forward" id="btnRight">Move Right</button>
<button type="button" title="Backward" id="btnLeft">Move Left</button>

<select name="FieldstoBeMatchedOn" id="FieldstoBeMatchedOn" multiple="multiple" size="10">
</select>
```

I wrote the following code to move items from left dropdown grouped list to right dropdown grouped list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
defaultListBind = function (e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#FieldstoBeMatchedOn');
            alert(selectedOpts);
            $('#FieldstoBeMatchedOn').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
            $(selectedOpts).remove();
            //e.preventDefault();
        }
        // defaultListBind();

        $('#btnRight').click(function (e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#AvailableFields option:selected');
            if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                alert("Nothing to move.");
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            $('#FieldstoBeMatchedOn').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
            $(selectedOpts).remove();
            defaultSelect();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#btnLeft').click(function (e) {
            var selectedOpts = $('#FieldstoBeMatchedOn option:selected');
            if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                alert("Nothing to move.");
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            $('#AvailableFields').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
            $(selectedOpts).remove();
            defaultSelect();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
defaultSelect = function () {
            $("#FieldstoBeMatchedOn option").each(function () {
                $(this).prop("selected", true);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

How can I move items from left dropdown list to right dropdown list in a grouped or category format?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sridharnetha/vgdkykrr/3/)

I really appreciate your help in advanced.

Comment: It seems to work when you remove the unwanted ` });`

Comment: use identity (===) operator instead of  equality (==) operator bcoz == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type === will simply return false.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.You have to find  a way to remove the groups when there is nothing in the right side

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {    
$('#btnRight').click(function (e) {
                var selectedOpts = $('#AvailableFields option:selected');
                if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                    alert("Nothing to move.");
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

    if(selectedOpts.parent().attr('label') == "Group A"){
        $('#FieldstoBeMatchedOn').append($('<optgroup label="Group A">')).append($(selectedOpts).clone());
                $(selectedOpts).remove();
                defaultSelect();
                e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
        $('#FieldstoBeMatchedOn').append($('<optgroup label="Group B">')).append($(selectedOpts).clone());
                $(selectedOpts).remove();
                defaultSelect();
                e.preventDefault();
    }
            });

            $('#btnLeft').click(function (e) {
                var selectedOpts = $('#FieldstoBeMatchedOn option:selected');
                if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                    alert("Nothing to move.");
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

                $('#AvailableFields').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
                $(selectedOpts).remove();
                defaultSelect();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
    defaultSelect = function () {
                $("#FieldstoBeMatchedOn option").each(function () {
                    $(this).prop("selected", true);
                });
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="AvailableFields" id="AvailableFields" multiple="multiple" size="10">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <optgroup label="Group A">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group B">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>

    <button type="button" title="Forward" id="btnRight">Move Right</button>
    <button type="button" title="Backward" id="btnLeft">Move Left</button>

    <select name="FieldstoBeMatchedOn" id="FieldstoBeMatchedOn" multiple="multiple" size="10">
    </select>
```

Comment: Move left not inserting value into on the matched group.